# Unable to parse JSON to UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsdictionary, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

Currently I'm trying to parse `responseObject` to populate my table view, but I've been having some problem with parsing the array in the responseObject. I want to populate my cell with values from `responseObject[@"test"]`.

**Request operation:**

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager POST:[kBaseURL stringByAppendingString:@"directori/member_list"]parameters:params
      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
          NSLog(@"RESPONSE: %@", responseObject);
          if ([responseObject[@"status_reason"] isEqualToString:@"Success"]) {
              self.allMembers = responseObject[@"test"];
              NSLog(@"MEMBERS: %@", self.allMembers);
          } else {
              // handle error
          }
      } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
          NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);
      }];
```

As you can see below, `test` is an array of objects.

**Sample responseObject:**

```
RESPONSE: {
    test =     (
                {
            img = "http://test.com/assets_api/images/no_image.png";
            location = "test location";
            name = "test user";
            position = "test";
        }
    );
    "audit_no" = "";
    "status_code" = 200;
    "status_reason" = Success;
}
```

And here's is my table view data source.

**Table View Data Source**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"DirectoryCell";
    DirectoryViewCell *cell = (DirectoryViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell==nil) {
        cell = [[DirectoryViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSDictionary *member = [self.allMembers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"MEMBER: %@", member);
    return cell;
}
```

`allMembers` is of type `NSArray` while `member` is of type `NSDictionary`.
When I try to log the value of `member` it returns null. Where did it go wrong?

Answer (score -1):

You Should try this

```
NSDictionary *member = [[self.allMembers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectAtIndex:0];
```